# Are there performance gains to using WHERE ST_IsValid?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 with PostGIS 2.0.1 on Windows.

Consider a table `some_table` with a `GEOMETRY` column named `geom`.

Query 1:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET geom = ST_MakeValid(geom)
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET geom = ST_MakeValid(geom)
WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(geom)
```

Does calling `ST_IsValid` as a filter (as in Query 2) offer any performance gains (over Query 1)?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see. I imagine it'd depend on the proportion of the data that's invalid, on whether there's a functional index on `some_table USING (ST_IsValid(geom))` and the relative costs of `ST_IsValid` vs `ST_MakeValid`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think it would be a rather uncommon use case for there to be an index on validity. No?

Comment: Very, but you never know how some folks will set things up, or who else will be reading this with a different goal or situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Craig's comment, the answer is "maybe."  There are a lot of possible answers here and it depends on a lot of things.

For example, suppose 80% of your table is invalid and you care about that 20%.  And now suppose that ST_IsValid takes 60% of the CPU time that ST_MakeValid does.  You would run the ST_IsValid on all of your table (0.6 * 1) plus you would run the ST_MakeValid function on the other 20% (1 * 0.2).  This would save you about 20% of your time without an index.  If you had a functional index it might save you a bunch of time (the numbers are hypothetical of course).

Suppose on the other hand half your table was invalid.  You'd run the cheaper function on all rows (0.6 * 1) and you would run the more expensive function on the other (1 * 0.5), leading to a net slowdown in your query by about 10%.  This also means that if virtually all your rows are valid there can be no benefit performance-wise to checking.

So the answer is that you really need to check with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on your specific set.